# in openssh, can i specify a command to be executed for every login attempt?

Tags: linux, ssh, security

I get a lot of ssh login attacks and want to reduce them.
is there any way i can specify a command for openssh to execute and check its return value and only allow the login attempt if this command returns 0 ?

the reason behind this is that i would like to be able to have more complex login rules which i can express in a script rather than through simple filewall/ip-based rules.

Comment: @DavidGeorge That link doesn't help much...

Comment: you are pointing me to a bash wiki page but what do you meaning with that? what i try to do is to outsource the login logic from ssh to a command so that i can do anything i can think of. for example i could POST the (attempted) login data to a webserver using curl and if this webscript returns an "ok" i would allow the login. basically you would have more flexibilty with such an option.

Comment: Maybe there is a better solution for you, but it would be dependent on what you're trying to do. Sorry my previous post got cut short. I was referring to en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29 for bash login scripts. You could put your script in there to kill the session if your "criteria" isn't met

Comment: so you mean i should basically allow every connection and check for the criteria in the login shell? would i be able to read the attempted password from this login script? if yes i think that might be good enough for me if that is not too dangerous. post it as an answer and i will accept it then.

Comment: @dnagy Just an FYI, I always move SSH services to nonstandard ports on the servers I run. On the same server/IP, I've seen SSH attempts go from hundreds a day to zero simply by changing the port. This does not help you solve the question you asked, but I just wanted to make you aware of this as an option to help increase security even further.

Comment: I would encourage you to rethink your approach.  Trying to handle secure logins with a homegrown script is likely to decrease rather than increase security.  The O'Reilly SSH book has essentially the same thing to say so be careful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, with a sufficiently modern openssh there is a trick: use the AuthorizedKeysCommand. This configuration option lets you specify an external command to retrieve SSH keys. In here you can put logic like retrieving SSH keys from LDAP, but also any other logic you want. As long as you accept only key-based authentication, not returning any keys will make authentication fail.

In older versions of openssh you can use ForceCommand, but that's a forced command *after* authentication, not a command that gets executed *before* authentication. It does however work with both password and key based authentication.

If you want to support password based authentication and want to plug into the authentication phase, you will need to write your own PAM module and make it required for SSH authentication. This is not the most trivial of ways, and does not get called for key based authentication.

If all you want to do is block IP addresses that have too many authentication failures, fail2ban can help you as well, requiring no changes to your SSH setup.

Comment: ah i see. but you already have pointed out the problem with that. it is a command that gets executed after the login and has nothing to do with the login-logic itself :-/

Comment: AuthorizedKeysCommand is part of the login logic itself, it's onl ForceCommand that's done after login.

Comment: this looks like a good solution. it is nearly exactly what i wanted but with keys instead of passwords.

Comment: thank you for your answer. i think this solution is good enough for me right not. anyway as you are mentioning PAM. i have just found a pam module called pam_exec ( http://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_exec ) . the description of that looks promising. But i will experiment with it later.

Comment: Some 3rd party security softwares might also be listed in this answer : denyhost and fail2ban